# Inserting an element vs. showing a hidden element

Tags: javascript, html, css

Which is best practice for displaying an HTML element that is initially to be hidden?

- Create the element in the HTML and hide it with CSS. When it is time to use it, show it with JavaScript.
- When the element is needed, create and show it with JavaScript.

The downside to the former is that a potentially unnecessary element is in the HTML and must be initially hidden with CSS. The downside to the latter is that HTML is in the JavaScript file.

**EDIT: Adding Examples**

One example would be adding a loading indicator or displaying a modal window.

Comment: Depends on the specific need. Sometimes you may have a hidden element and update it with different content multiple times, showing/hiding it.

Comment: Also depends on if it is one or two small elements, one or two large elements, thousands of elements.. etc.

Comment: I think it mainly comes down to the number of times it needs to be shown/or hidden. If it is more than one, definitely the former, because otherwise you are just creating HTML over and over again unneededly. It also depends on the number of elements, because creating and appending a bunch of elements through loops or something will take much longer than just hiding or showing existing HTML.

Comment: Thanks for all of your great points so far. This is much more subjective than I originally realized, so there isn't necessarily an certain best practice here.

Comment: Yup.  We came.  I actually think this is an interesting question and could be a great discussion...but the format of SO doesn't really allow these kinds of non-objective, non-answerable questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot more factors that go in to this.  If you are inserting a small element like a link or select list options, then dynamically generating them in javascript is a non-issue.  If you are generating a repeating series of complex HTML, it might be a good idea to create a template of the html in the markup (so that the web designers can maintain it) and then make the template hidden in CSS.   Then use javascript (e.g. jQuery) to clone the template and insert it in to the DOM.  This gives you the benefit of using more native implementations to extend the DOM tree without all the nasty javascript-that-parses HTML mess.

But ultimately the practicality comes down to this: Who is going to maintain the code?  Will the more elegant solution be something that the maintainer will understand?  Or will putting everything in javascript (despite its inelegance) be something that a junior coder would be able to expand or update as the need arises in the future?

The vast majority of web browsers run on hardware that is ridiculously over-powered for what the user actually "needs", at least in terms of web browsing.  Because of this, inefficient solutions in Javascript are rarely ever an immediate issue.  If you are targeting mobile browsers though, efficiency == battery life.  So if you are doing heavy dom-manipulation then consider the suggestion above and see if it works for your case.

Best of luck!
-Brendan

Answer (score 1):

The answer to that question used to be very heavily biased towards "Don't create it until you need to."

The reasons behind that decision are still somewhat applicable,but no-where near as much as they were.

- People running a browser with styles off will see your hidden content.  They'll also see a **very** ugly web.  I wouldn't worry about it.
- People running very ancient browsers that don't support styles will see it.  They'll also see a very **broken** web.  I'd not worry about them either
- Screen readers will pick it up.  Modern screen readers seem to be much better at realizing what content is, and is not visible.  If you need ADA compliance, or just want to be responsible, some testing might be done there.
- Sometimes, when printing, hidden content would be picked up.  Again, not an issue.

All said, I'd do for hiding it through CSS rather than trying to dynamically add the content.